# Arrays - Why is the subscript operator tied to the identifier?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, operators

Why is the subscript operator of an array tied to the identifier?

Cuz when we write:

```
int a[5];
```

a is actually of type "int[5]"

This prohibits to make use of the following:

```
typedef int[3][3] matrix_t;
....
void foo(matrix_t my_matrix){
  ....
}
```

What's the benefit of the actual implementation?
I really would like to have this feature or did I miss something?

Comment: `typedef int matrix_t[3][3]`

Comment: or `using matrix_t = int[3][3]`

Comment: This is c++ only right?

Comment: pick one.......

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please remove the unrelated tag!

Comment: This question wasn't language specific. And since arrays in C++ are based on arrays in C I wanted to left that open. On the contrary I was interested in how it works for both languages.

Answer (score 3):

In C, you type variables in the way you'd use them.

They are sort of like "frozen expressions".

So

```
int x[5][2];
```

means you'd use `x` by passing it first a value up to `5` in `[]`, then a value up to `2` in `[]`, and what you assign that value to is an `int`.

In a sense, this reuses the expression-parsing engine to type things.

`typedef` works like declaring a variable, except whatever the variable would be becomes an alias for that type.  So instead of

```
typedef int[3][3] matrix_t;
```

it is

```
typedef int matrix_t[3][3];
```

again, this reuses the variable declaration parsing/grammar for defining type aliases.

In C++11, we have `using` that works more like you might want:

```
using matrix_t = int[3][3];
```

---

A final part of your problem is that matrices in C cannot be copied or passed by value.  `int[3][3]` types as function parameters become `int[3]*` types -- pointers to `int[3]`s.  And you cannot return an `int[3][3]` type period.

In C++, this is fixed via `std::array`:

```
std::array< std::array< int, 3 >, 3 >
```

is a type that is layout compatible with `int[3][3]` (at least in practice), but can be passed around like a value even to/from functions.  In C you'd do:

```
struct matrix {
  int data[3][3];
};
```

which has the same layout in memory as the above `std::array`, and can be passed to/from functions like a value.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a historical legacy from the early ages of C language development. Back then it was decided that declaration of an entity should mimic its future usage. So, array declarations look similar to the way arrays are used in expressions. The same applies to function declarations, pointer declarations etc. (`*` in pointer declaration is also "tied to the identifier")

In modern C++ in some contexts you can actually use the new syntax, which follows the logic you suggested. It applies to using-declarations for typename aliases (similar to classic typedef-declaration)

```
using array_type = int[3];
// Same as
// typedef int array_type[3];
```

or contexts like function return type declarations

```
auto foo() -> int (*)[3]
{
  ...

// Same as
// int (*foo())[3]
```

Comment: Every language has its grammar. Not sure what you mean with "legacy"; it is just the way C was set up. That statement could be applied to every other language, too.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm just commenting on the matter of *why* the grammar was setup that way back in the day when it was initially set up. We did not receive C grammar on stone tablets from outer space, you know. The grammar was created by people. And that is why they created it in that specific way (or at least what some sources state on the matter of "why")

Comment: My point is just that the "legacy" argument is true for **every** programming language, including the relatively new Go, Rust or Swift. There was some grammer choosen and later version have to use it (once the language has a large enough user-base at least).